# Unable to change a variable through parameter in a method

Tags: java

```
private int superCount = 0;


public void calculator(JFXButton buttonName,int price,String name,int count){
    float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageButton.textProperty().get())/100;
    totalPrice += price*percentage;
    count++;
    status.setText(name+" has been added");
    String totalPriceString = String.format("%,.0f", totalPrice);
    priceLabel.setText("£"+totalPriceString);
    buttonName.setText(name+" : "+count);
}
public void addSuper(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    calculator(superButton,superPrice,"Super",superCount);
}
```

So I'm passing `superCount` into calculator. Then I'm incrementing `count` by 1. However, since that `count` is actually `superCount` (at least I thought it was) it's not actually changing `superCount`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth pointing out that you don't need to pass it in if you've already declared `supercount` outside of these methods - you can just increment `supercount` from within calculator(). If they are in different classes:

**Java is pass by value and not pass by reference.** So if you pass a value into a method, you're not changing the original value, only the new value that you've passed in.

`count` only exists inside your calculator method. You can't change the value of `supercount` without *returning* a value from calculator.

```
// If you change calculator to return an it
public int calculator(...) {

  return count;
}
```

Now you could do:

```
supercount = calculator(superButton,superPrice,"Super",superCount);
```

Comment: The fact stills remain that if you're declaring `supercount` outside of this method... you don't need to pass it in, in the first place. You can just increment `supercount` from within calculator.

Comment: Yes but I will be using calculator for multiple counts. So there will be different counts being incremented.